# How can I fix Sass Calc for width not working

Tags: css

I try use calc in sass but not working. Plese help me check it.
`width: calc((100% - 237px) * 25%)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to give a better example if you explained what you were trying to style, but can you just replace the `* 25%` with a `/ 4`? That works for me.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/o9mw5beu/